# Javascript: Find douplicated values from array with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, key

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

I want to be able to find duplicated values from JavaScript array.

The array keys can be duplicated so I need to validate only the array values.

Here is an example :

```
var arr=[
    Ibanez:     'JoeSatriani',
    Ibanez:     'SteveVai',
    Fender:     'YngwieMalmsteen',
    Fender:     'EricJohnson',
    Gibson:     'EricJohnson',
    Takamine:   'SteveVai'
];
```

In that example:

the key is the guitar brand
the value is the guitar player name.

So:

If there is duplicated keys (like: `Ibanez` or `Fender`) as on that current example that is OK :-)

But

If there is duplicated values (like: `EricJohnson` or `SteveVai`) I'm expecting to get (return) that error:

```
EricJohnson,SteveVai
```

Comment: *"Array with keys"*? Sorry but that doesn't exist in Javascript, your data structure is either wrong or different.

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words. Provide an example of the data structure you're actually dealing with that will correctly parse (the one shown will not), show the result you want, explain any logic for getting from the former to the latter that may not be blindingly obvious (e.g.: explain all of it), and explain what part of implementing that logic you're having trouble with.

Comment: You can't have the same keys

Comment: Well, I thought that it might be super easy but just to clarify:

Guitar brands can be duplicated values, Guitar players not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have associative arrays in Javascript. You can create an array of objects, like:

```
var arr=[
    {Ibanez:     'JoeSatriani'},
    {Ibanez:     'SteveVai'},
    {Fender:     'YngwieMalmsteen'},
    {Fender:     'EricJohnson'},
    {Gibson:     'EricJohnson'},
    {Takamine:   'SteveVai'}
];
```

Then you'll need a `for...in` loop to go over every object in the array, create a new array of values and check *that* for duplicates, which is also not very straightforward - basically you'll want to sort the array and make sure no value is the same as the one after it.

```
var arrayOfValues = [];

arr.forEach(function(obj){
    for(var prop in obj)
        arrayOfValues.push(obj[prop]);
});

arrayOfValues.sort(); // by default it will sort them alphabetically

arrayOfValues.forEach(function(element,index,array){
   if(array[index+1] && element==array[index+1])
     alert("Duplicate value found!");
});
```

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, because it does work: http://jsfiddle.net/v39zs2wh/1/

Comment: I did NOT vote down... sorry for that but it's working on my end :)

Comment: Nah didn't mean to call you out or anything. Just generally wondered.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, object keys can not be repeated.

This means that:

```
({
    "Fender": "Jim",
    "Fender": "Bob"
})["Fender"]
```

Would simply return: "Bob".

However, I did make a code that could allow you to find duplicates in values, but as I said, the key will have to be unique:

```
var arr = {
    Ibanez: 'EricJohnson',
    Fender: 'YngwieMalmsteen',
    Gibson: 'EricJohnson',
    Takamine: 'SteveVai',
    "Takamine2": 'SteveVai'
};

function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var track = [];
var exists = [];
for (var val in arr) {

    if (contains(track, arr[val])) {
        exists.push(arr[val]);
    } else {
        track.push(arr[val])
    }
}

alert(exists)
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/dr09sga6/2/

Comment: Nice Coding Man! Impressive :-) I understand that I will need to use array of objects instead as  @Sidd mention on his answer

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, the example array you provided isn't a valid JavaScript array. You could, however, keep a list for each guitar type:

```
var mapping = {
    Ibanez:     ['JoeSatriani','SteveVai'],
    Fender:     ['YngwieMalmsteen','EricJohnson']
    Gibson:     ['EricJohnson'],
    Takamine:   ['SteveVai']
];
```

Or a list of each guitar/musician pair:

```
var pairs = [
    ['Ibanez','JoeSatriani'],
    ['Ibanez','SteveVai'],
    ['Fender','YngwieMalmsteen'],
    ['Fender','EricJohnson'],
    ['Gibson','EricJohnson'],
    ['Takamine','SteveVai']
];
```

Your solution is going to depend on which pattern you go with. However, in the second case it can be done in one chained functional call:

```
pairs.map(function(e) {return e[1]})  // Discard the brand names
.sort()  // Sort by artist
.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
  if (i>0 && a[i]==a[i-1] && !p.some(function(v) {return v == c;})) p.push(c);
  return p;
},[]);  //Return the artist names that are duplicated
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkurqmqd/1/

To break that `reduce` call down a bit, here's the callback again:

```
function(p,c,i,a){
      if (i>0 
          && a[i]==a[i-1] 
          && !p.some(function(v) {
             return v == c;
          })) 
            p.push(c);
      return p;
}
```

`reduce` is going to call our callback for each element in the array, and it's going to pass the returned value for each call into the next call as the first parameter (`p`). It's useful for accumulating a list as you move across an array.

Because we're looking back at the previous item, we need to make sure we don't go out of bounds on item 0.

Then we're checking to see if this item matches the previous one in the (sorted) list.

Then we're checking (with `Array.prototype.some()`) whether the value we've found is ALREADY in our list of duplicates...to avoid having duplicate duplicates!

If all of those checks pass, we add the name to our list of duplicate values.

Comment: Added some explanation as to how that works. `map` and `reduce` aren't hard once you're familiar with them. Just requires thinking in a bit of a new way.